# Apollo Server Express 3 returns unexpected null value after a while

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Apollo server express v3 works like a charm, and it returns properly
however, after a while of hitting server on intervals,
it returns null instead of the correct response

I can see in the server console log that the returned value is correct in the resolver, but something gets messed up with the graphql itself.

After server restart, it works fine again.

This occurs every once in a while for no apparent reason.

Has anyone encountered the same issue and have a solution for it?

Comment: Could you add the relevant gql and resolver code where you're seeing this? Is this only occurring for a specific field or all fields for that resolver?

Comment: it happens 3 times out of 10. so far only for a specific resolver field where i hit it every 5 seconds on an interval. i will add a github repo when the workload is lighter as i opened a github issue for it. however, it is a pretty basic build, nothing special